# How to Troubleshoot SQL Database Import Errors

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

We are moving a local SQL Server Express database into Azure.

The database has been exported via:

```
SQL Server Management Studio -> 
Right Click Database ->
Generate Scripts -> 
Select Specific Database Objects -> 
Tables -> 
All Tables -> 
Save as Script File -> 
Advanced -> 
SCHEMA and DATA -> 
GO
```

After importing the data, All tables are created, and about half of the data is imported successfully before the script reports:

> Query completed with errors

The error being reported is:

> A fatal scripting error occurred.
> Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing 1.

I have been searching Azure and locally for an error log or anything with the ability to troubleshoot this issue to determine which specific query/import is failing and I can't find it.

I imagine there is a quote character or an encoding issue that is breaking the import, and I'd like to avoid exporting and importing the 100+ table database row by row to find the issue.

PS. I've tried querying the `sys.event_log` for information and it reports:

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'sys.event_log' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Comment: Why don't you just back-up to url blob storage and restore directly to Azure?

Comment: Feel free to give specific instructions and if they work I'll mark your answer.

Comment: @Stu `*.bacpac`-based imports break very easily if your DB uses _any_ feature that is even slightly different in Azure SQL (e.g. User/Login mappings, PolyBase External Tables, XEvents, Linked tables, SQLCLR, etc). Doing a manual schema-first-then-data export is the most reliable, but it also requires you to know what to change in the generated  DDL first. Fun...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Server Management Studio to migrate a SQL Server database (on a local computer) to Azure SQL most of the times ends in frustration. My suggestion for you is to use Azure Data Migration Assistant (DMA) to make that migration easy.

First use DMA to perform [an assessment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assesssqlonprem?view=sql-server-ver16) just to make sure your SQL Server database does not have any incompatibilities with Azure SQL. If the results of the assessment do not show any blocking point then proceed to [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-ver16) your database.